# Admin and user control in a website

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, redirect, user-roles

I'm new to ASP.NET and I am designing a warehouse portal. It has three users: admin, warehouse staff and customer service. I designed an adduser.aspx page where I add users and assign roles. I use dropdown list to select the type of user and then store the value in database.
After creating all users I set my login page as default and after validation, redirect them to specific pages.
This is how I do it:

```
        if (displayusertype.Equals("Admin"))
            {
               Session["user"] = loginusername.Text;
               Response.Redirect("Admin_Default.aspx");
            }

        if (displayusertype.Equals("Warehouse staff"))
            {
               Session["user"] = loginusername.Text;
               Response.Redirect("Warehousestaff_Default.aspx");
            }
        if (displayusertype.Equals("Customer service"))
            {
               Session["user"] = loginusername.Text;
               Response.Redirect("Customerservice_Default.aspx");
            }
```

If I go to the Admin_Default.aspx directly from browser I can access it. But I want only the admins to access this page. Similarly for warehouse staff and customer representatives. I only want the page which is redirect to, after a login and not simply through a browser. How can i achieve it?

Comment: Always perform the authorization check on the page being requested, not on the page making the request.  Never assume that users can't forge their own requests.

Comment: @David  My navigation is as follows:

Default page (login page - after authorization)  ---> default admin page / default warehouse user page/ default customer service page. From default admin page I'm redirecting admin to add user page.  But the add user page can be accessed directly. How should I do the authorization there?

Comment: Don't use [stringly typed](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?StringlyTyped) variables.

Comment: any suggestions on what I should look into @EBrown

Comment: @user1377504: Well, how do you know if a user is a specific type of user?  That's the authorization check you would perform.

Comment: You should not be using `displayusertype.Equals()`. First, `strings` provide a `==` operator (`displayusertype == "Admin"` etc.). (This isn't Java.) Second, you should use a more meaningful datatype. Possibly an `enumeration` or similar to indicate what `type` the user is.

Comment: @EBrown: `string.Equals()` can be *very* useful if one wants to provide different equality comparison rules.  Even with default equality comparison, there's no compelling reason not to use it.

Comment: @David Though that is true (provided you use one of the overloads that takes a `StringComparison` argument) there's no compelling reason to use it *either*. See this [MSDN](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2004/03/29/when-should-i-use-and-when-should-i-use-equals.aspx) article. `My rule of thumb is that for almost all reference types, use Equals when you want to test equality rather than reference identity. The exception is for strings - comparing strings with == does make things an awful lot simpler and more readable` It's largely a *best-practices* argument.

Comment: Can you use [ASP.net authorization](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wce3kxhd(v=vs.140).aspx)? That will likely be more secure and simpler